# How to "merge" two result sets by date

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to merge the results of the two SQL queries below:

**uploads table**

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`), SUM(uploaded) AS total_upload FROM uploads;

date          total_download

2014-09-11    1000
2014-09-12    1000
2014-09-13    1000
```

**downloads table**

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`), SUM(downloaded) AS total_download FROM downloads;

date          total_upload

2014-09-09    1000
2014-09-10    1000
2014-09-11    1000
```

And I would like to get the following results, with blank results if there's no downloads and blank results where there's no uploads:

```
date          total_download   total_upload

2014-09-09                     1000
2014-09-10                     1000
2014-09-11    1000             1000
2014-09-12    1000
2014-09-13    1000
```

I thought I could left join the tables on download_date = upload_date but obviously the days where there is no uploads will be missing. How would I go about merging these results properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FULL JOIN` with `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(u.date, d.date) AS date,
    u.total_upload AS total_upload,
    d.total_download as total_download
FROM (SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) AS date, SUM(uploaded) AS total_upload FROM uploads) as u
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) AS date, SUM(downloaded) AS total_download FROM downloads) as d
    ON u.date = d.date
```

Syntax may be off; I'm rusty with MySQL.

Edit:  If you want exactly blanks, you'll need to substitute: `COALESCE(CAST(u.total_upload AS varchar),'') AS total_upload` or similar.  Note that that actually changes your output data types to characters, however.